# Can’t tell if this black stuff is mold

Tags: mold, closet

I found a strange looking substance on a shelf in my closet. I can’t tell if it’s mold or just dirt/grime. A picture is attached below. I wiped it down with vinegar/baking soda/detergent, and some of it went away.
Thanks for the help.
[image]

Comment: What was kept on that shelf?

Comment: No clue. It’s a college dorm.

Comment: Contact the dorm maintenance staff and ask them.

Answer (score 2):

Generally mold does not grow on what looks like a melamine surface. That looks like it just dirt or something rubbed of from whatever was on that shelf.